# Magento 2 REST API Authorization failed while creating product

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api

I am trying to create a simple product using REST Api. The client is a node.js script,

I have created an admin user with access to all the resources,
and used the credentials to request a token which i am getting successfully in a response. but when i try to use that token and post the product data, i get following response

```
Consumer is not authorized to access %resources
{ resources: 'Magento_Catalog::products' }
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(286): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->checkPermissions()
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(255): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->validateRequest()
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(160): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#6 /var/www/html/magento2/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#7 {main}
```

Note that

1. I have given access of all the resources to the user.
2. I am getting the token from this endpoint `integration/admin/token`
3. The request i am sending in the post is like following

   ```
   { sku: '24-MB01-DUP',
   store_view_code: '',
   attribute_set_code: 'Bag',
   product_type: 'simple',
   categories: 'Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Bags',
   product_websites: 'base',
   name: 'Joust Duffle Bag Duplicate',
   description: '<![CDATA[<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can\'t be beat - not in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it\'s ideal for athletes with places to go.<p>\n<ul>\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\n<li>L 29" x W 13" x H 11".</li>\n</ul>]]>',
   short_description: '',
   weight: '',
   product_online: '1',
   tax_class_name: 'Taxable Goods',
   visibility: 'Catalog, Search',
   price: '34.0000',
   special_price: '',
   special_price_from_date: '',
   special_price_to_date: '',
   url_key: 'joust-duffle-bag',
   meta_title: '',
   meta_keywords: '',
   meta_description: '',
   base_image: '/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg',
   base_image_label: '',
   small_image: '/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg',
   small_image_label: '',
   thumbnail_image: '/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg',
   thumbnail_image_label: '',
   swatch_image: '',
   swatch_image_label: '',
   created_at: '3/15/16, 10:41 AM',
   updated_at: '3/15/16, 10:41 AM',
   new_from_date: '',
   new_to_date: '',
   display_product_options_in: 'Block after Info Column',
   map_price: '',
   msrp_price: '',
   map_enabled: '',
   gift_message_available: '',
   custom_design: '',
   custom_design_from: '',
   custom_design_to: '',
   custom_layout_update: '',
   page_layout: '',
   product_options_container: '',
   msrp_display_actual_price_type: '',
   country_of_manufacture: '',
   additional_attributes: 'activity=Gym|Overnight|Trail|Travel,features_bags=Waterproof|TSA Approved|Lockable,material=Nylon|Polyester,strap_bags=Adjustable|Cross Body|Detachable|Double|Padded|Shoulder,style_bags=Luggage|Duffel|Exercise',
   qty: '100.0000',
   out_of_stock_qty: '0.0000',
   use_config_min_qty: '1',
   is_qty_decimal: '0',
   allow_backorders: '0',
   use_config_backorders: '1',
   min_cart_qty: '1.0000',
   use_config_min_sale_qty: '1',
   max_cart_qty: '0.0000',
   use_config_max_sale_qty: '1',
   is_in_stock: '1',
   notify_on_stock_below: '',
   use_config_notify_stock_qty: '1',
   manage_stock: '0',
   use_config_manage_stock: '1',
   use_config_qty_increments: '1',
   qty_increments: '0.0000',
   use_config_enable_qty_inc: '1',
   enable_qty_increments: '0',
   is_decimal_divided: '0',
   website_id: '1',
   related_skus: '',
   crosssell_skus: '',
   upsell_skus: '24-MB03,24-MB05,24-MB06,24-MB02,24-UB02,24-WB03,24-WB07,24-WB04',
   additional_images: '/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg',
   additional_image_labels: 'Image',
   hide_from_product_page: '',
   bundle_price_type: '',
   bundle_sku_type: '',
   bundle_price_view: '',
   bundle_weight_type: '',
   bundle_values: '',
   associated_skus: '' }
   ```

I know that the data in the request is disoriented and not structured but I don't think that it should have anything to do with authorization, the data format deserves its own error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with authorization while testing REST Api in Postman. Following steps helped me:

1. Disable add secret key URLs in Magento
2. Added following to PostMan:

   - Content-Type: `application/json`
   - Authorization: `Bearer webapi_token_from_dev\tests\functional\etc\config.xml`